# HTML Email Signature Compatibility

Tags: html, email, signature

I wanted to know how to make HTML Email Signature compatible with popular mail clients like Gmail, Apple Mail, Outlook, etc. ?

Thank You ^_^ .

Well, I searched the web about this topic but unfortunately couldn't find anything useful.
Some were using email signature generator, some were using divs but I was taught to use only tables.
I am very much confused.

Any kind of help will be really really appreciated.

Thank You again & have a nice day *_* .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML email signatures are kind of tricky, mainly on Outlook. I'm learning that too and I haven't found a blog or community. A good resource that has helped me is this https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. It helps you to avoid using, for example, flexbox layout in an HTML email signature. What I do is focus just on the ones that have all checks on that page.

I hope that helps : )